# A set of First and Second Category

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

> Suppose that for each irrational $q \in \mathbb{R}$, an equilateral triangle in the plane is constructed such that one vertex is at $(q,0)$ and its opposite side is above and parallel to the x-axis. Prove that $\cup_{q \in \mathbb{R\setminus Q}} T_q$ must contain a rectangle of the form $[a,b] \times (0, \epsilon)$.

Proof: Let $K_\epsilon =\{ q \in \mathbb{R\setminus Q}$ : the size of $T_q \geq \epsilon \}$. We thus have $\mathbb{R\setminus Q} = \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} K_{1/n}$. We know the irrational is of second category, but the RHS is of first category, thus for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $K_{1/n}$ is dense for some interval $[a,b]$. Therefore, $[a,b] \times (0, 1/n] \subseteq T_q$.

This is the proof my professor gave for this, but I am confused as to how it works. Namely, the part where we have that the LHS is of second category, meanwhile the RHS is of second.

Comment: What he meant to say is that not every $K_{1/n}$ can be first category, else the RHS would be a countable union of first category sets, which would make the RHS a first category set .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things I don't understand about your question.  Such a $T_q$ is not unique, no?  What is the side length?  Also, what does "size of $T_q$" mean?  In any case, perhaps this will help.

$\mathbb{R}$ is not [meager](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Meagre_set) by the [Baire Category Theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Baire_category_theorem#/Statement_of_the_theorem).  It must then be the case that $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathrm{c}}$ is not meager, because if it were, then $\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{Q}^{\mathrm{c}}\cup \bigcup _{q\in \mathbb{Q}}\{ q\}$, a countable union of meager sets, would be meager.

Thus, if we have $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathrm{c}}=\bigcup _{m\in \mathbb{Z}^+}K_{1/m}$, it must be the case that some $K_{1/m_0}$ is *not* nowhere dense.  Thus, there must be some open $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ such that $K\cap U$ is dense in $U$.  $U$ will contain a closed interval $[a,b]$, and so $K\cap [a,b]$ will be dense in $[a,b]$.

As I'm not exactly sure what you mean by $T_q$, I'm afraid I can't say more, but hopefully this is of some use.

Comment: No, $T_q$ is not unique, it just need be that every irrational point has some triangle. By size in this case it means the height.